# How to prevent "wrap_content" text view from pushing another view out of sight?

Tags: android

I have two text views in a layout. I would like to display them next to each other like so:

|[TextView1][TextView2]                          |

Width of the first text view can vary dramatically. From several symbols up to a 100 symbols, but I would like to ellipsize it if it is too long and TextView2 should always be visible. Like so:

|[TextView1TextView1Tex...][TextView2]|

I have tried the following layout, but it displays TextView2 always at the end of the screen:

[TextView1]                          [TextView2]|

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have tried to change the width of TextView1 from 0 to wrap_content, but then it pushes the TextView2 out of the sight like so:

|[TextView1TextView1TextView1Text...]|

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try to make use of layout_weight.

Comment: set both textview layout_weight = 1.

Answer (score 10):

It may be a overkill, but `TableLayout` does the trick.

```
<TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shrinkColumns="0">

        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

`android:shrinkColumns="0"` is the catch here. It tells the table to only  shrink the first column while keeping the others untouched. The result is that the system will only resize the first column, i.e. your first TextView.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I didn't mention that I have multiple rows, which makes it harder because TextView1 can be very long on some rows and very short on others.

Comment: Wow, finally correct answer. Tried everything and didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this solution, it works for me, 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:text="Second Textview" />

</LinearLayout>
![enter image description here][1]

Output: Check below Screen shot:
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately your solution divides the screen in half, which means that I cannot place TextView2 closer to the edge if TextView1 is too long.

Answer (score 1):

Not very proud of this solution, but it does the trick,
I have set width of both TextView1 and TextView2 to "wrap_content"

Then in the code I have set maxWidth of TextView1 to 80% of it's parent like so:

```
view.setMaxWidth((int)(((View)view.getParent()).getWidth() * 0.8));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify weight for only one of the child elements,you are telling android that that view is the only on whose visibility you care about.However if you specify weight for both Child views.That ensures that both are visible.

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" //this makes sure both views are displayed
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like the TextView to be more flexible. Move as closer as possible to TextView1 if it is short and move to the very end of the screen if  TextView1 is too long.

Comment: you remove the margin left from the 2nd text view, ND you keep varying the weights. for example give the second TextView a weight of 0.25